# Problem with Matplotlib subplots with different number of rows and columns

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code below creates a 4x4 grid of plots as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(10)
rows, cols = 4, 4
_, axs = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(5,5))
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        axs[i,j].plot(x,x)
```

[image: 4x4]

But things go wrong when I try to display subplots with 2 rows and 4 columns (same code with `rows, cols = 2, 4`):

[image: 2x4 result]

When I would expect something like this:

[image: 2x4 expected]

If I try to add `axs[i,j].set_aspect('equal', 'box')` after each plot, I get:

[image: 2x4 meh]

Which is somehow better, but still leaves an empty line, just as if the default "tall rectangle" figure was leaving its footprint. Overall I have the impression that matplotlib wants its subplots to look "square-y".

Before I look into complicated layout matters, does anybody know about some straightforward way to come up with the result I'm expecting (which is not so crazy to expect, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decreasing the rows, but keeping the figure the same size. You would need to adjust the figsize. So since you cut the rows in half, cut the height in half too to stay proportional.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(10)
rows, cols = 2, 4
_, axs = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(5, 2.5))
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        axs[i,j].plot(x,x)
```

[image]

Comment: OK I thought figsize was meant to be the individual figure size - so I understand this is the overall figure size! That was straightforward indeed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should adjust the figsize:

```py
_, axs = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(5, 5./2))
```